# Facing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 when I try to getitem from local storage bu passing a parameter

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, local-storage

This is what I get in my browser console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at recommendDetails (index.js:8)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at c (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

The code it is pointing to

```
$(function() {
   recommendDetails(); // here    
});

function recommendDetails(){
    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recommended_project')); //here
    var project_data = [];
    if(data.length != 0) {

            $(data).each( function(i, key){
                if(i < 3){
                    var x = '<li data-id="'+ data[i].FLAT_ID +'" data-blocktype="'+data[i].block_name+'"><div class="cardsection card-section-styling"><div class="card-top '+ flat_type +'"><label class="info-label '+ b +' ">'+ data[i].price +'</label><div class="item-overlay onhover-color top"></div><div class="button1" data-flatid="'+ data[i].flat_type +'"> Show More </div></div><div class="card-bottom"><div class="card-icon-center background-color-cardbhk bhk-icon-img"></div><div class="bhk-header center"><h2>'+ data[i].flat_type +'</h2><h4> <span class="txt-uppercase">' + data[i].project_name+'</span> - ' + data[i].block_name + '</h4><a class="link" href="booking.html?'+ data[i].PROJECT_ID +','+ data[i].BLOCK_ID+','+ data[i].FLAT_ID +','+ data[i].flat_no +'">Book</a></div></div></div></li>'    
                    project_data +=x;
                }
            });
            console.log(project_data);
}
```

I set my localstorage here

```
function flat_detials() {
    var t = {
        method: "POST",
        url: baseurl + "flats_details"

    }
    $.ajax(t).done(function (response) {
        var p = JSON.stringify(response[1].projectDetails);
        var r = JSON.stringify(response[2].RecommendedFlats);
        localStorage.setItem('project_details', p);
        localStorage.setItem('recommended_project', r);
        // recommendedProjects();
        if(response.status === true ){


        }
    });
}
```

Due to this problem none of my api calls are not working.

I am not able to figure out where I might be going wrong, I checked the JSON format and that too is valid, Please help me figure out where I am wrong. Thanks!
P.S : I am still an amateur at this so pardon if this seems like a repeated question.

Comment: what do you get when you do `console.log(localStorage.getItem('recommended_project'));`? Also you can check the server response for your ajax call in the developper tools (in "Network" tab, click on the corresponding request and then "response"). A JSON beginning by "u" might be that what you get as response is a script error

Comment: @Kaddath There is no json beginning with "u"

Comment: your error tells me there actually is: ` Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check null value before  JSON.parse,

```
$(function() {
   recommendDetails(); // here    
});

function recommendDetails(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('recommended_project')){
        var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('recommended_project')); //here
        var project_data = [];
        if(data.length != 0) {

            $(data).each( function(i, key){
                if(i < 3){
                    var x = '<li data-id="'+ data[i].FLAT_ID +'" data-blocktype="'+data[i].block_name+'"><div class="cardsection card-section-styling"><div class="card-top '+ flat_type +'"><label class="info-label '+ b +' ">'+ data[i].price +'</label><div class="item-overlay onhover-color top"></div><div class="button1" data-flatid="'+ data[i].flat_type +'"> Show More </div></div><div class="card-bottom"><div class="card-icon-center background-color-cardbhk bhk-icon-img"></div><div class="bhk-header center"><h2>'+ data[i].flat_type +'</h2><h4> <span class="txt-uppercase">' + data[i].project_name+'</span> - ' + data[i].block_name + '</h4><a class="link" href="booking.html?'+ data[i].PROJECT_ID +','+ data[i].BLOCK_ID+','+ data[i].FLAT_ID +','+ data[i].flat_no +'">Book</a></div></div></div></li>'    
                    project_data +=x;
                }
             }
            });
            console.log(project_data);
}
```

Comment: I have added what you suggested, but still I am getting the same issues.

Comment: have you check what you get in `localStorage.getItem('recommended_project')` in console

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('recommended_project')
"undefined"` this is what I get.

Comment: @Kavya then you stringified an undefined var, and stored the string "undefined". Can you update the question with what's in `response` as a result of the Ajax call? You probably get the properties wrong from the response

Comment: @Kavya also check Kaddath thoght